# Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: docker

I am new in docker, and i am working on MAC.
i am using docker compose to containerize my dotnet api,
but when i try to do a migration after "docker-compose up" i have the error "Login failed for user 'sa'."
but when running the app locally using this sql server image i can be able to connect.
the two containers are running and this is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
build: .
 container_name: web
 ports:
  - "8000:80"
 depends_on:
  - db
 networks:
  - connection
db:
image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest"
container_name: db
environment:
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "P@$$w0rd!"
  ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
  UserID: "sa"
ports:
- "1433:1433"
networks:
  - connection
```

networks:
connection: driver: bridge

and this is my connection strings :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=sa;Password=P@$$w0rd!"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker-compose.yml, the `$$` is an escaped `$` since `$something` expands the variable. Therefore:

```
P@$$w0rd!
```

becomes

```
P@$w0rd!
```

and the application will attempt to connect with the wrong password. You can escape both `$`'s with:

```
MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "P@$$$$w0rd!"
```